# Unable to load test file using bazel

Tags: java, bazel

I have the following project structure:

```
project/
   - app/
   - test/
      - java/
         - Utils.java
      - resources/
         - file.json
         - BUILD.bazel
   - BUILD.bazel
```

I'm trying to load the `file.json` as a `File` object in order to use it to test some classes.
In `Utils.java`, I try to read it as:

```
public class Utils {
    public static File getSnapshotTestData() {
        File file = new File(Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file.json").getFile());

        // Added this part to test the file was loaded correctly
        try {
            String data = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8"); // throws FileNotFound Exception
            System.out.println("Data: " + data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
}
```

Even though if `file.getAbsolutePath()` returns a path like `/scratch/xxxx/.bazel/output/d03a9523f165711d724c4ed2c7f8d270/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin...`, if I try to read the file, I get FileNotFound.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Added in my bazel files the following:

**project/BUILD.bazel**

```
ARCHIVES = [
    "//xxx/xxx/app/src/test/resources:file.json",
]

java_junit5_test(
    name = "snapshot_admin_app_test",
    srcs = glob(["src/test/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/test/resources/**/*.*"]) + ARCHIVES,
    test_package = "com.xxx.xxx",
    deps = DEPS + TESTING_DEPS,
)
```

**project/test/resources/BUILD.bazel**

```
exports_files(["file.json"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include this in the `data` attribute:

```
java_junit5_test(
    name = "snapshot_admin_app_test",
    srcs = glob(["src/test/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/test/resources/**/*.*"]) + ARCHIVES,
    data = glob(["src/test/resources/**/*.*"]),
    test_package = "com.xxx.xxx",
    deps = DEPS + TESTING_DEPS,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with loading resource files from the src/main/resources folder. Below is the answer from the Bazel slack channel:

> When you use bazel run on a java target, all resource files will be built into jars corresponding to their java_library targets meaning you can't use getFile on them directly. Try getResourceAsStream

> If the files are in the data param, they will be available on $PWD when you use bazel run, but they won't be built into the deploy jar and they won't be on the class path

using getResourceAsStream did the trick for me