# how to import variables from a json file to attributes in BUILD.bazel?

Tags: json, bazel

I would like to import variables defined in a json file(my_info.json) as attibutes for bazel rules.
I tried this (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/5.3.1/skylark/tutorial-sharing-variables.html) and works but do not want  to use a .bzl file and import variables directly to attributes to BUILD.bazel.

I want to use those variables imported from my_info.json as attributes for other BUILD.bazel files.

projects/python_web/BUILD.bazel

```
load("//projects/tools/parser:config.bzl", "MY_REPO","MY_IMAGE")
container_push(
  name = "publish",
  format = "Docker",
  registry = "registry.hub.docker.com",
  repository = MY_REPO,
  image = MY_IMAGE,
  tag = "1",
)
```

Asking the similar in Bazel slack I was informed the is not possible to import variables directly to  Bazel and it is needed to parse the json variables and write them into a .bzl file.

I tried also this code but nothing is written in config.bzl file.

my_info.json

```
{
    "MYREPO" : "registry.hub.docker.com",
    "MYIMAGE" : "michael/monorepo-python-web"
}
```

WORKSPACE.bazel

```
load("//projects/tools/parser:jsonparser.bzl", "load_my_json")
load_my_json(
    name = "myjson"
)
```

projects/tools/parser/jsonparser.bzl

```
def _load_my_json_impl(repository_ctx):
    json_data = json.decode(repository_ctx.read(repository_ctx.path(Label(":my_info.json"))))
    config_lines = ["%s = %s" % (key, repr(val)) for key, val in json_data.items()]
    repository_ctx.file("config.bzl", "\n".join(config_lines))

load_my_json = repository_rule(
    implementation = _load_my_json_impl,
    attrs = {},
)
```

projects/tools/parser/BUILD.bazel

```
load("@aspect_bazel_lib//lib:yq.bzl", "yq")
load(":config.bzl", "MYREPO", "MY_IMAGE")

yq(
    name = "convert",
    srcs = ["my_info2.json"],
    args = ["-P"],
    outs = ["bar.yaml"],
)
```

Executing:
% bazel build projects/tools/parser:convert

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/michael.taquia/Documents/Personal/Projects/bazel/bazel-projects/multi-language-bazel-monorepo/projects/tools/parser/BUILD.bazel", line 2, column 22, in <toplevel>
                load(":config.bzl", "MYREPO", "MY_IMAGE")
Error: file ':config.bzl' does not contain symbol 'MYREPO'
```

When making troubleshooting I see the execution calls the jsonparser.bzl but never enters to **_load_my_json_impl** function (based in print statements) and does not write anything to **config.bzl**.

Notes: Tested on macOS 12.6 (21G115 ) Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0

```
There is a better way to do that? A code snippet will be very useful.
```

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192209/unable-to-load-test-file-using-bazel) can you try putting the file in data attribute .

Comment: Hello @SG_Bazel, using data attribute how can I use the variables defined in json file as attributes for other targets?
 I added some lines to my questions in order to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: The line `load(":config.bzl", "MYREPO", "MY_IMAGE")` is wrong.

You should try to `load("@myjson//:config.bzl", "MYREPO", "MY_IMAGE")`

Answer (score 0):

Bazel always works in 3 phases:

1. load - it parses tree of WORKSPACE / BUILD / .bzl files; macros are expanded and dropped
2. analysis - rules (impl) are interpreted to produce actions
3. execution - actions (e.g. "run gcc with args") are executed

Unfortunately, in solution you've described your "load" depends on results of "analysis".

I wish Bazel would have capabilities to load json/yaml/whatever-bazel-agnostic on load phase... Even lifting ".bzl" extension requirement in "load" would be a relief.